# How to find and replace multiple lines in Perl script?

Tags: regex, perl, replace, find, using

Im trying to write a perl script replacing multiple lines with some text i wanted. I wrote the below lines and it did not work.

```
s/<cl:doc-meta>(.*)<\/cl:doc-meta>/something/gi;
```

This is what I want to find and replace

```
<cl:doc-met>

<cl:title></cl:title>

<cl:isbn length="13"></cl:isbn>

</cl:doc-meta>
```

Please suggest me how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you forgot the `s///mgi` m - Flag. m = multiline.

Comment: is his XML? How about using a proper parser?

Answer (score 1):

Use the modifier "s" - treats as single line.

```
$string =~ s/<cl:doc-meta>(.*)<\/cl:doc-meta>/something/sg;
```